# Text Similarities. Cosine Similarity. Specify results

Tags: python

I just finished my first cosine similarity code and successfully coded the results. However, I would like to display the result in a more specific way. Is there any way to see how the 37.8% was calculated? Very cool would be of course also a graphic or anything similar.

Here is my code:

```
f=open (r"C:\Users\Output11.txt")
doc1=str(f.read())
f1=open(r"C:\Users\Output22.txt")
doc2=str(f1.read())
def cosine_distance(s1, s2):
    allsentences=[doc1 , doc2]

    from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
    from scipy.spatial import distance

    vectorizer=CountVectorizer()
    all_sentences_to_vector = vectorizer.fit_transform(allsentences)
    text_to_vector_v1 = all_sentences_to_vector.toarray()[0].tolist()
    text_to_vector_v2 = all_sentences_to_vector.toarray()[1].tolist()
    cosine = distance.cosine(text_to_vector_v1, text_to_vector_v2)
    print('Similarity of two sentences are equal to ',round((1-cosine)*100,2),'%')
    return cosine
cosine_distance(doc1 , doc2)
```

The result is as I said:

```
Similarity of two sentences are equal to  37.8 %
```

Comment: You have just to make some prints... Your percentage is calculated by doing `round((1-cosine)*100,2)`. So, you can do a print of the `cosine`.

Comment: Plotting: you can check the library `matplotlib`.